# Informix External Tables DROP

Tags: external, informix

I am trying to unload data from an internal Infomix table into an external file using the following stored procedure.

```
    create table table_name(
    column1 int,
    column2 int
    )
    insert into table_name(column1, column2) values(1, 1);
    insert into table_name(column1, column2) values(2, 2);
    insert into table_name(column1, column2) values(3, 3);
    =====================================================


    create procedure spunloaddata(p_unload_filename varchar(128))
    returning
    int as num_recs ;
    DEFINE  l_set   SMALLINT;
    DEFINE  l_statusCode int;
    DEFINE  l_exec_string lvarchar(4000);
    DEFINE l_unique_id INT8;


    DEFINE l_num_recs smallint;
    ON EXCEPTION
         SET l_set

    IF (l_set = -535) THEN  -- already in TRANSACTION
    ELIF (l_set = -244) THEN  -- row locked
        RETURN l_set;
    ELIF ((l_set <> -958) AND (l_set <> -310 ))THEN  -- temp table already exists
        RETURN -1;
    END IF
    END EXCEPTION WITH RESUME;

    TRACE ON;    

    -- TRACE OFF;
    SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT 30;

    SET ISOLATION TO DIRTY READ;
        LET l_num_recs = 0;
        LET l_unique_id = MOD(DBINFO("sessionid"), 100000) * 100000 + DBINFO('UTC_CURRENT');


        -- get all EMAIL notifications
        LET l_exec_string = 'SELECT column1, column2 '                        
                            ||  ' FROM table_name  '                        
                            || ' INTO EXTERNAL ext_temp_EMAILnotifications' || l_unique_id
                            || ' USING (DATAFILES("DISK:'
                            || TRIM(p_unload_filename)
                            || '"))';

        TRACE l_exec_string;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_exec_string;
        LET l_statusCode = SQLCODE;
        LET l_num_recs = DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2');

        IF(l_statusCode <> 0) THEN
            LET l_num_recs = l_statusCode;
        END IF

    BEGIN
        ON EXCEPTION IN (-206) END EXCEPTION WITH RESUME;
            LET l_exec_string = 'DROP TABLE ext_temp_EMAILnotifications' || l_unique_id;
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_exec_string;
    END

        RETURN l_num_recs ;
    END PROCEDURE;

    ===========================================================================
    execute stored proc

   ===========================================================================
    dbaccess "databasename"<<!
    execute procedure spunloaddata("/tmp/foo.unl");
    !
```

The external tables are not getting dropped and my database is filling up with these tables. The stored procedure is going into -206 error (the specified table is not in the database) at the "DROP tablename" code. I can see the table being created.

When I do a dbaccess databasename and go into tables and Info, I see all the ext_temp_uniqueid tables listed. When I try to manually drop these tables through dbaccess, I get the same -206 error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question — I learned the new(ish) INTO EXTERNAL syntax.  However, it would be preferable if you provided something more nearly an MCVE ([MCVE]).  As it is, people have to fill in a whole lot of details by guesswork, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  An MCVE, however, would include an outline schema for a table (not necessarily 'the table') with a few (2-5) columns.  It would include a few (2-5) rows of data.  And the SELECT statement would be correspondingly simpler (it isn't likely to be the conditions that cause the trouble — it's likely the "INTO EXTERNAL" and the external table names that cause the trouble. You'd be able to demonstrate a call to the procedure, and list the directory containing the external data before and after the procedure runs. The extra you've provided allows the MCVE adaptations; that helps.

Comment: Which Informix version are you using? Tried your example on Informix 12.10.FC12 and it is dropping the external tables.

Comment: Informix 12.10.FC8

Comment: As @LuísMarques suggested, it was the version of Informix. Once we upgraded to 12.10.FC12, it started dropping the tables. Thank you.